# WSL2 "read-only" file system while building chromium

Tags: linux, ubuntu, chromium, wsl-2

I'm attempting to build chromium on WSL2 according to [this guide](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src.git/+/HEAD/docs/linux/build_instructions.md).

When I get to the `fetch --nohooks chromium` everything is loading and then I get the following error:

```
OSError: [Errno 30] Read-only file system: '/home/ghadar/chromium/src/third_party/libprotobuf-mutator/_gclient_src_0ve3yqhz'
```

I've looked everywhere and couldn't find any explanation to this error.

I'm running WSL2 on Windows 11 with Ubuntu 20.04 as the Linux distribution.

Answer (score 2):

I've run into the similar issue when disk space was running out while extracting a big package in WSL, it got resolved by cleaning up the disk giving it big enough free space, shutting down the WSL in Windows power shell with command "wsl --shutdown", then restarting the WSL.

Answer (score 1):

A few possibilities that I can think of:

- Filesystem corruption (it happens)
- Out of disk space on the host Windows drive

For the first one, see [#6220 on the WSL Github](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/6220).  Recommended solution is (and it might be a good idea to backup any critical files first):

```
# Identify the correct drive:
mount | grep ext4

# Take the drive returned (e.g. /dev/sdd) and:
sudo e2fsck /dev/sdd -p
```

It could also be a disk-space issue.  The Chromium source is pretty large at around 57GB.  Is it possible that you are out of disk space on the Windows drive?  If so, then WSL still thinks it has space remaining, because it is on a sparse virtual disk that can grow up to (250GB/1TB depending on the WSL release), but once space on the host drive is gone, WSL probably set the device read-only.

If that's the case, and you have a larger drive (SSD/NVMe recommended for performance, of course), you can "move" the virtual disk if you'd like -- See [my Super User answer](https://superuser.com/a/1731302/1210833) on the topic.

Or you might try fetching without the full repo history, as suggested in the docs, with the `--no-history` flag.